# Encoding error while writing CSV from Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, decoding

Exploded an data frame and trying to write data in CSV format from data frame. 
Data has bangla text. While writing it getting constant error. Tried almost everything. But not working.

Here is sample data:

```
  [{
    "reward_amount": ",8192",
    "code": "*21291*189#",
    "reward_names": ",Airtel Bonus",
    "name": "Apr20_ACLM_D_USSD_Tk189_8GB_30D_MdUsrNCCN_17-24May",
    "reward_validity": ",30",
    "offermsg_channel": "SMS",
    "validity": "38",
    "offermsg_head": "AirtelOffer",
    "revenue_cat": "Dt,",
    "offer_msg": "\n\n\u09ee \u099c\u09bf\u09ac\u09bf - \u09e9\u09e6 \u09a6\u09bf\u09a8, \u09e7\u09ee\u09ef \u099f\u09be\u0995\u09be! \u0986\u099c\u0987 \u09a1\u09be\u09df\u09be\u09b2 \u0995\u09b0\u09c1\u09a8 *\u09e8\u09e7\u09e8\u09ef\u09e7*\u09e7\u09ee\u09ef#!\n\n",
    "action": "USSD",
    "reward_type": "Debit Revenue Info,ADCS Data Pack",
    "DUMP_DATE": "20200415 17:30:16",
    "deno_debit": "189",
    "CAMP_ID": "158035"
  },
  {
    "reward_amount": "",
    "reward_names": "",
    "name": "APR20_ACLM_V_EL_TK16_48P_30D_NRMTIC_16-30",
    "reward_validity": "",
    "offermsg_channel": "SMS",
    "validity": "17",
    "offermsg_head": "Best_Rate",
    "revenue_cat": "",
    "offer_msg": "\n\n   \u098f\u09df\u09be\u09b0\u099f\u09c7\u09b2\u09c7 \u09f3\u09e7\u09ec \u09b0\u09bf\u099a\u09be\u09b0\u09cd\u099c\u09c7 \u09ea\u09ee\u09aa/\u09ae\u09bf+\u099f\u09cd\u09af\u09be\u0995\u09cd\u09b8-\u09e9\u09e6\u09a6\u09bf\u09a8 \u0995\u09ae \u0996\u09b0\u099a\u09c7 \u09ac\u09c7\u09b6\u09bf \u0995\u09a5\u09be \u09b8\u09ac \u09a8\u0982\n\n",
    "action": "Recharge",
    "reward_type": "Discounted tariff",
    "DUMP_DATE": "20200415 17:30:14",
    "deno_debit": "16",
    "CAMP_ID": "158101"
  }]
```

Code written(please note explode function works perfectly. Its just data that can't be written due to encoding):

```
import numpy as np
import json
import pandas as pd    

def split_dataframe_rows(df,column_selectors, row_delimiter):
    # we need to keep track of the ordering of the columns
    def _split_list_to_rows(row,row_accumulator,column_selector,row_delimiter):
        split_rows = {}
        max_split = 0
        for column_selector in column_selectors:
            split_row = row[column_selector].split(row_delimiter)
            split_rows[column_selector] = split_row
            if len(split_row) > max_split:
                max_split = len(split_row)

        for i in range(max_split):
            new_row = row.to_dict()
            for column_selector in column_selectors:
                try:
                    new_row[column_selector] = split_rows[column_selector].pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    new_row[column_selector] = ''
            row_accumulator.append(new_row)

    new_rows = []
    df.apply(_split_list_to_rows,axis=1,args = (new_rows,column_selectors,row_delimiter))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)
    return new_df


if __name__=="__main__":
    with open('E:\\PyCharm_Data\\icms_campaign_dump_reward_list.json','r',encoding='utf-8-sig')  as rfh:
        data = json.load(rfh)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df.keys())
        lst = ('reward_type','reward_amount','reward_names','reward_validity','revenue_cat')
        df['reward_amount'] = df['reward_amount'].astype('str')
        df['reward_names'] = df['reward_names'].astype('str')
        df['reward_type'] = df['reward_type'].astype('str')
        df['reward_validity'] = df['reward_validity'].astype('str')
        df['revenue_cat'] = df['revenue_cat'].astype('str')
        df=split_dataframe_rows(df,lst,',')
        print(df)
        with open('csv_data.psv','w') as wfh:
            df.to_csv(wfh,sep='|',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Errors that I get: 
**Pycharm**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PyCharm_Projects/hawk_Eye/make_csv_data.py", line 109, in <module>
    df.to_csv(wfh,sep='|',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
  File "E:\PyCharm_Projects\hawk_Eye\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "E:\PyCharm_Projects\hawk_Eye\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 202, in save
    self._save()
  File "E:\PyCharm_Projects\hawk_Eye\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 324, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "E:\PyCharm_Projects\hawk_Eye\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 356, in _save_chunk
    libwriters.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels, self.cols, self.writer)
  File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u09ee' in position 93: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Linux**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make_csv_data.py", line 114, in <module>
    df.to_csv(wfh,sep='|',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1745, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 151, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 263, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 290, in _save_chunk
    self.cols, self.writer)
  File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u09ee' in position 100: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should be done to resolve this error?